# Why does R show a different version of the OS than what is installed?

Tags: r, apple-m1

Why does R show a different version of the OS than what is installed?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

According to `?sessionInfo`

> Where R is compiled under an earlier version of macOS (as the CRAN distribution has been) but running under ‘Big Sur’, macOS reports itself as 10.16 (which R recognizes as ‘Big Sur’) and not 11.x.

```
osVersion
#[1] "macOS Big Sur 10.16"

sessionInfo()$running
#[1] "macOS Big Sur 10.16"
```

Comment: OK, that make sense. I was also expecting a speed increase when I upgraded to the apple silicon native support, but I got none. Anybody did the same?

Comment: begin = Sys.time()
x = rnorm(100000000, mean = 0, sd = 1)
end = Sys.time()
end- begin

Comment: Both took about 9.7 sec

Comment: @user3482393 For me it is 11.09 sec

Comment: Surprised that the 4.1 apple native R offered no increased in speed over the 4.0.5 version for 64-bit intel Macs and Rosetta2 combo.

Comment: i got 6.5 seconds on a 2015 mac running mojave

Comment: @user3482393 I believe your question was about the version issue and not the timings.